# VBA - WebScraping Get elements for classname for equal classNames

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, web-scraping, getelementsbyclassname

I want to extract two values (numbers and positions) per player which have an equal class name "text". I am currently unable to select the two correct values per player.

My problem is I actually have only the first and the second value in "HTMLnumbers" and "HTMLposition". Otherwise if I select all items for the class "text", the first player gets the value for number and the second player gets the value for position. Thats also not correct.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub erweiterteWerte()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLplayerRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Dim HTMLnumbers As Object
Dim HTMLposition As Object

Dim numbers As String
Dim position As String

Dim letzteZeile As Long
Dim aktuelleZeile As Long

IE.Visible = False
IE.Navigate "https://examplexyz.de"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:7"))

Set HTMLdoc = IE.Document

Set HTMLplayerRow = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("playerRow")
Set HTMLnumbers = HTMLplayerRow(0).getElementsByClassName("text")

   If Not HTMLnumbers Is Nothing Then
   numbers = HTMLnumbers.Item(0).innerText
   position = HTMLnumbers.Item(1).innerText
    
   Else
     numbers = "no_value"
   End If

Debug.Print numbers
Debug.Print position

IE.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: `HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("players")` - I don't see this in your screenshot.  Seems like `HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("playerRow")` would give you a collection of `playerRow` elements, and you would query each of those for the child elements specific to each player.

Comment: @TimWilliams I added a better screenshot. I hope my question is now better understandable.

Comment: Tim's suggestion is correct, its easier to get a collection of playerRow then query the info within each item as you can be sure it will be specific to a player.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great support! I edited my coding and updated my post above. Now I get the first pair for the first player. This looks correct. But I need the data for all players. I tried to add a for loop, but it doesnt work. I wonder why. Any idea? `For i = 0 To HTMLPlayers(0).getElementsByClassName("playerRow").Length - 1` and `next i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but to illustrate the basic approach:

```vb
Sub erweiterteWerte()

    Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim playerRows As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim playerBadges As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim player As Object, badge As Object
    
    Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = False
    IE.Navigate "https://play.kickbase.com/transfermarkt/kaufen"
    
    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:07"))
    
    Set HTMLdoc = IE.Document
    Set playerRows = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("playerRow")
    
    For Each player In playerRows
        
        Debug.Print "---------------"
        Debug.Print classText(player, "firstName") & " " & classText(player, "lastName")
        
        Set playerBadges = player.getElementsByClassName("badge")
        For Each badge In playerBadges
            Debug.Print badge.innerText
        Next badge
    
    Next player
    
    IE.Quit

End Sub

'Helper function to get a child (of `obj`) element's text using its className
'  (only handles a single instance but could be extended)
Function classText(obj As Object, classname As String) As String
    Dim els As Object
    Set els = obj.getElementsByClassName(classname)
    If els.Length > 0 Then
        classText = els(0).innerText
    Else
        classText = "[not found]"
    End If
End Function
```